# Ammeter with and without magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current

Is there *any* kind of ammeter that measures the current without using magnetic field?

Can we deduce that presence of a magnetic field may interrupt current readings for normal ammeters?

Comment: Current meters don't measure magnetic fields. They may measure induced currents in conductive loops, so you may pick up magnetically coupled noise from an AC magnetic field. This can be avoided by making the area of the loop as small as possible. The easiest experimental technique to achieve that is by using twisted wires, which, if used correctly, should suppress such AC contributions by 50-80dB. If that's not enough you need to either filter the signal and/or use magnetic shielding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are ammeters which are usually used in AC circuits which measure current on the basis of Joule heating of the ammeter wire.

You can use a simple compass needle. If the deflection of the needle is appreciable, say about 3 degrees, it will probably interfere with the reading of a shunted-galvanometer ammeter.

Answer (score 1):

Any ammeter which uses a shunt resistor will ignore magnetic fields (if it is well-designed), and measure only the voltage across the shunt. Since the shunt is a known resistance, $$i = \frac{V}{R}$$ For instance, this is the standard way a DMM measures current.